# Python docs: Importing everything from python package convention not clear

Tags: python

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) say:

> If `__all__` is not defined, the statement `from sound.effects import *` does not import all submodules from the package `sound.effects` into the current namespace; it only ensures that the package `sound.effects` has been imported (possibly running any initialization code in **init**.py) and then imports whatever names are defined in the package.

The first clause (before ';') says **does not import**, the second clause says **then imports whatever names are defined**. Isn't that a contradiction to the first clause? Logically, everything is imported eventually, so why this convolued wording?

Comment: "[it] does not import all **submodules** ... it then imports whatever **names ...**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important distinction is "imports whatever names are defined in the package" vs "does not import all submodules".

Submodules aren't automatically names in the package `__init__` module (unless explicitly imported to be).

IOW, with a package

```
foo/
  __init__.py
  baz.py
```

with `foo/__init__.py` containing

```
def bar():
   print("bar")
```

the statement

```
from foo import *
```

will only bring the function `bar` into scope (from `foo/__init__.py`), but not `baz` (a submodule in the `foo` package) into scope, **unless** it's a name in `foo/__init__.py`, á la

```
from . import baz
```

---

To refer to the `sound/` hierarchy in the linked docs (in an abridged form, and assuming there is no code in those `__init__.py` files):

```
sound/
  __init__.py    # Initialize the sound package
  formats/       # Subpackage for file format conversions
    __init__.py
    wavread.py   # Read WAV files
```

this means that your application doing

```
from sound import *
```

will not put `formats` in the scope and

```
from sound.formats import *
```

won't give you `wavread` either.

Comment: "won't bring baz (a submodule) into scope" - what's the point of `from foo import *`, then? It contains only baz.

Comment: Also, you write 'Submodules aren't names in the package module'. Docs define `package` and `module`. What is `package module`?

Comment: @user3156459 Clarified into post.

Comment: Can you base you answer on the package structure from the docs?  `sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
              ...
      effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
            
              ...`

Comment: Sure. Added another paragraph

Comment: `foo/__init__.py containing` you probably mean `foo/baz.py`?

Comment: No, I mean `foo/__init__.py`.

Comment: `The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages. This prevents directories with a common name, such as string, unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__ variable, described later.` Looks like `def bar()...` would not be allowed in __init__.py, no?

Comment: No – any code is perfectly allowed in `__init__.py` just like in any other module. [For instance, the stdlib's `json` package has a bunch of code in `__init__.py`.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/json/__init__.py)

Comment: So, a `package` can exist without any `module` in it? With some names defined in its __init__.py? Why would one want such a package?

Comment: A package can exist without submodules. e.g. a `sound/__init__.py` with some code in it is perfectly valid and practically equivalent to just `sound.py`. Maybe you know that your package will need submodules in the near future, and you want a headstart.

Answer (score 0):

If `__all__` is not defined it will import every name from the module that does not start with an `_`.

```
def _private(): ...  # won't import

def public(): ...    # will import
```